# Setup Wizard to install other applications

Tags: c#, c++, c, vb.net

I got a one-off question. I have an application, and I want to make a Setup Wizard for it.

I want to make the wizard due to what my program does.

Quick overview of my program to help relay what I am looking for.

My program is basically a big shortcut program. I have buttons such as Active Directory, VNC, RDP, ect. When clicking it, it will open said program.

Now, the reason I want the wizard is because some computers don't have the programs I have setup (I currently have a tab built in, where the users can change the path for each program), such as VNC. So I would like the Wizard to install my program, and during that, run the VNC installer and/or Active Directory ect.

I have seen online, there are Setup Wizard making programs, but I am not sure if that will have what I want to do. Any ideas guys?

Thanks in advance!

Note: My program is written in VBNET, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use iexpress? Just go to run(Windows Key + R) and type "iexpress" (without the qoutes)

Answer (score 0):

You could right click on your solution, go to Add Project, and then select the InstallShield template (May be named 'Enable Installshield if you haven't set it up yet) under Other Types > Setup and Deployment